# Android Methods are undefined

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent

Please, i had a problem i'm programing my app and use similiar code for other activities and work fine but here i got some errors i don't know.

- The method onCreate(Bundle) is undefined for the type Object

  - The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type 
    SesionActivity
  - Line breakpoint:SesionActivity [line: 22] - onCreate(Bundle)
- The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}
- The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

layout

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <!--  Sample Dashboard screen with Two buttons -->

    <!--  Button to create nueva transaccion -->
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnTransaccion"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nueva transaccion"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dip"/>

    <!--  Button to create cerrar sesion -->
    <Button android:id="@+id/btncerrarsesion"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cerrar Sesion"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dip"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

SesionActivity.java

---

```
package com.felipe.tesis;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView.FindListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SesionActivity {

    Button btnNTransaccion;
    Button btnCloseSesion;

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.sesion_iniciada);

            //Buttons
            btnNTransaccion = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTransaccion);
            btnCloseSesion = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncerrarsesion);

            btnNTransaccion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // Launching All products Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TransaccionActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });
     }
}
```

---

Answer (score 4):

You simply forgot to extend the Activity class.

Change this:

```
public class SesionActivity {
```

To this:

```
public class SesionActivity extends Activity {
```

Answer (score 2):

Your main class does not extend `Activity`. The methods you're accessing (`onCreate`, `startActivity`, etc.) can be found within [the `Activity` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

It should be:

```
public class SesionActivity extends Activity {
```

Comment: Great minds think alike and within 4 seconds of each other... (upvote)

Comment: @Sam Agreed! Voted likewise. :)